# Как получить имена всех папок и файлов из формы с опцией webkitdirectory в django?

Tags: python, django, form

Есть форма:

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" webkitdirectory  name="file-upload">
    <button>Send</button>
</form>
```

Во views.py в request.FILES я получаю только список документов, а хотелось бы поучить вложенность документов с папками на подобии утилиты tree для командной строки